# How do you know if wine has gone bad?

Tags: wine

Which smells indicate that wine/beer is bad?and can it have any negative effect on health?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list from the [Wine Faults Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_fault) page. These faults, for the most part, will not do any harm when they are in wine (they aren't strong enough) They just taste bad.

**Acetaldehyde**    Smell of roasted nuts or dried out straw. Commonly associated with Sherries where these aromas are considered acceptable

**Amyl-acetate**    Smell of "fake" candy banana flavoring

**Brettanomyces**   Smell of barnyards, fecal and gamey horse aromas Cork taint Smell of a damp basement, wet cardboard or newspapers and mushrooms

**Butyric acid**    Smell of rancid butter

**Ethyl acetate** Smell of vinegar, paint thinner and nail polish remover

**Hydrogen sulfide**    Smell of rotten eggs or garlic that has gone bad

**Iodine**  Smell of moldy grapes

**Lactic acid** bacteria    Smell of sauerkraut

**Mercaptans**  Smell of burnt garlic or onion

**Oxidation**   Smell of cooked fruit and walnuts. Also detectable visually by premature
    browning or yellowing of the wine

**Sorbic acid** plus lactic acid bacteria   Smell of crushed geranium leaves

**Sulfur dioxide**  Smell of burnt matches. Can also come across as a pricking sensation in the nose.